# How to tell a dimension of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

[image]

How to tell the dimension of a subspace?

I know it is depending on the numbers of linear independent basis. But in the question, it already has two independent basis, and I can already think of a lot more independent basis other than $u$ and $v$..

Comment: Rather the dimension is the number of vectors in some basis. Have you a candidate for a basis of this space?

Comment: You can think the dimension as being the number of degrees of freedom to build a vector belonging to that space. Is this case, once you know $x_1$ and $x_2 - x_1$, you know the entire vector..

Comment: if $x_2-x_1 = x_3 - x_2$ then $x_1 - 2x_2 + x_3 = 0$ which means we already have a dependency.  For every additional $x_n$ we introduce we have the same dependency.  There are at most 2 independent vectors in the space.

Comment: The wording of the question makes it seem like you think that $u$ is a _basis_ of the subspace. This is not true. This indicates either bad writing (in which case you should be more careful to use the correct words) or bad understanding.

Comment: @DavidK Why isn't u is a basis of the subspace?

Comment: Because a _basis_ of a two dimensional space consists of two vectors. A one-vector basis can only be a basis of a one-dimensional space. And $u$ is just a single vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dimension theorem for vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces) states that all bases of a vector space have the same number of elements. So if you can determine the cardinality of one basis, you have determined the dimension.